# how to refer to the next item in a list and compare it to the item before it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I have a homework question where it asks to make an algorithm which would go through every element in the list and see if the number beside it is greater than the current number or not. If it is not greater than the current number, then the counter will go up by 1, if it is greater the counter will stay where it is.
I got it to work but it only works if there are more than 3 items in the list.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def count(items):

if len(items) == 0:
    return 0



else:
    count = 0
    for i in items:
        count += 1
        items1 = items[i:]
        items2 = items[i+1:]

        if items1 > items2:
            return count - 1



print (count([42, 7, 12, 9, 2, 5])) #returns 4. works but does not work if len < 3
print (count([])) #returns 0. works
print (count(list(range(10**7))))  # supposed to print out 1 since it's only 1 number, but it just gets stuck and doesn't finish the rest of the program
print (count([99])) # prints out none  
print (count(list(range(10**7,0,-1))))# supposed to print out 10000000 but prints 1 instead
```

Any kind of help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the algorithm statement is odd. What is "current number", the count or the current element? Assuming the current number then the first answer would be 2 since 12 > 7 and 5 > 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 0 or 1 elements - return 0.
You have to iterate over the length of the array, not over the elements themselves. There is a difference between:
`for i in array` and `for i in range(0,len(array))`

Be careful with the `range` - open a console and type python. Check what `range(10**2)` prints. It is not one element.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

```
def count(items):

    if len(items) == 0 or len(items) == 1:
        return 0
    else:
        count = 0
        for i in range(0,len(items)-1):
            items1 = items[i]
            items2 = items[i+1]

            if items1 > items2:
                count = count + 1
        return count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In general

def count_next_test(numbers, test_fn):
  count = 0
  last = len(numbers) - 1
  for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
    if i < last:
      if test_fn(n, numbers[i+1]):
        count += 1
  return count
```

In your case:  count_next_test(numbers, lambda a, b: a < b)

You could also do something like

```
pairs = zip(numbers, numbers[1:])
len([(a,b) for a,b in pairs if a < b])
```